# how to fix ERROR INSTALLING BOOTFEATURES?

Tags: sdn, onos

i am done downloading ONOS 2.7.0 in Ubuntu 20.04. Now i am running the command "./bin/onos-service start"
but it keeps showing the error see the attach photo below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj9fa.png)

i tried researching but found nothing.